# GitHub does not have download option

Tags: github, download

What is the fastest way of downloading files from:
https://github.com/pkmital/tensorflow_tutorials/tree/master/python/libs

This one does not have clone or download option.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a clone and download option on the root of the project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick reply!